# merge two columns into an array

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I want to merge two of my columns (`yanlis_cevaplar, cevap_icerik`) into an array and this code here gives me only one column in array when I print it (`yanlis_cevaplar`).

How do I fix it?

```php
$cevaplar = "SELECT yanlis_cevaplar FROM cevaplar";
$cevap_sonuc = $conn->query($cevaplar) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$cevap1 = array(); //create empty array
while ($row = $cevap_sonuc->fetch_array()) { //loop to get all results
    $cevap1[] = $row; //grab everything and store inside array
}

$cevaplar2 = "SELECT cevap_icerik FROM cevaplar";
$cevap_sonuc2 = $conn->query($cevaplar) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$cevap2 = array(); //create empty array
while ($row = $cevap_sonuc2->fetch_array()) { //loop to get all results
    $cevap2[] = $row; //grab everything and store inside array
}

$tumcevaplar = array_merge($cevap1, $cevap2);

print_r($tumcevaplar);
```

Comment: Instead of making two queries, just do one query where you select both columns: `SELECT yanlis_cevaplar, cevap_icerik FROM cevaplar`. Here's a basic MySQL tutorial for SELECT: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-select-query.htm

Comment: $cevaplar = "SELECT yanlis_cevaplar, cevap_icerik FROM 
              cevaplar";
              $cevap_sonuc = $conn->query($cevaplar) or 
              die(mysqli_error($conn));
              $cevap1 = array();//create empty array
                while($row = $cevap_sonuc->fetch_array()){//loop to get all 
              results
              $cevap1[] = $row;//grab everything and store inside array
               }

               print_r($cevap1);//this should give you everything
 
when I combine them like this how will I merge them? Sorry I'm a newbie.

Comment: Please add an edit to your question instead of writing it as a comment. It's pretty unreadable. And what do you mean by _"how will I merge them?"_ Have you actually looked at the result? There's no need to "merge" anything. The result will contain a multidimensional array with both columns. If that isn't what you want, you need to show us the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making multiple queries, you can just fetch all the columns you want in one single query:

```
$cevaplar = "SELECT yanlis_cevaplar, cevap_icerik FROM cevaplar";
$cevap_sonuc = $conn->query($cevaplar) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

// Now you can fetch all the rows straight away without any loop.
// The MYSQLI_ASSOC will return each row as an associative array
$result = $cevap_sonuc->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

print_r($result);
```

This will result in something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [yanlis_cevaplar] => some value
            [cevap_icerik] => some value
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [yanlis_cevaplar] => some value
            [cevap_icerik] => some value
        )

    ... and so on ..    

)
```

If this isn't what you want, then you need to show us an example.

I also recommend that you go through some basic SQL tutorials. How `SELECT` works is SQL 101. Here's one of *many* guides: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-select-query.htm

Comment: @AytugSeyrek - Cool!